# Understanding MON$STAT_ID in the Firebird monitoring tables

Tags: firebird, firebird2.1

I posted a few weeks back inquiring about the firebird DB and how to monitor it. Since then I have come up with a nifty script that monitors all of the page reads/writes/fetches/marks. One of the columns I am monitoring is the `MON$STAT_ID` and the `MON$STAT_GROUP` fields. This prints out a nice number for me; however, I have no way to correlate and understand what exactly it is. I thought printing out the `MON$STAT_GROUP` would help but it has yet to assist me in any way...

I have also looked into the `RDB$` commands but have found very limited documentation to see if they might assist me in monitoring my database.

So I decided to come here and inquire first off whether I am monitoring my database in a way that others can view the data from page reads/writes/fetches/marks and make an intelligent decision on whether or not the database is performing as expected.

Secondly, would adding `RDB$` commands to my script add anything to the value of the data that I will be giving our database folks?

Lastly, and maybe most importantly, is there anyway to correlate the `MON$STAT_ID` fields to an actual table in the database to understand when something is going on that should not be? I currently am monitoring the database every minute which may be to frequent, but I am getting valid data out. The only question now is how to interpret this data. Can someone give me advice on methods they use/have used in the past that have worked for them?

(NOTE: Running firebird 2.1)

Comment: What do you mean with "`RDB$` commands"? `RDB$` is the prefix of the system tables and a set of functions for obtaining context information, but I am unsure how those would would apply here.

Comment: I have added an answer, but as you don't provide details on what you are doing or what you need, it is not really possible to answer some parts of your question (eg your third paragraph would require your actual code for us to provide our insights)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The column `MON$STAT_ID` in `MON$IO_STATS` (and `MON$RECORD_STATS` and `MON$MEMORY_USAGE`) is the primary key of the record in the monitoring table. Almost all other monitoring tables include a `MON$STAT_ID` to point to these statistics: `MON$ATTACHMENTS`, `MON$CALL_STACK`, `MON$DATABASE`, `MON$STATEMENTS`, `MON$TRANSACTIONS`.

In other words: the statistics apply on the database, attachment, transaction, statement or call level (PSQL executes). The statistics tables contain a column called `MON$STAT_GROUP` to discern these types. The values of `MON$STAT_GROUP` are described in `RDB$TYPES`:

- 0 : `DATABASE`
- 1 : `ATTACHMENT`
- 2 : `TRANSACTION`
- 3 : `STATEMENT`
- 4 : `CALL`

Typically the statistics of level 0 contain all from level 1, level 1 contains all from level 2 for that attachment, level 2 contains all from level 3 for that transaction, level 3 contains all from level 4 for that statement.

As there might be data processed unrelated to the lower level, or a specific attachment, transaction or statement handle has already been dropped, the numbers of the lower level do not necessarily aggregate to the entire number of the higher level.

In Firebird 2.5 and earlier, there is no way to correlate the statistics to a specific table (as this information isn't table related, but - simplified - from executing statements which might cover multiple tables). As mentioned by Pavel Katalymov, Firebird 3.0 introduced the table [`MON$TABLE_STATS`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref-appx05-tablestats) which allows you to find statistics per table, see [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53664016/466862) (or the documentation of `MON$TABLE_STATS`) for an example.

As I also commented, I am unsure what you mean with "`RDB$` commands". But I am assuming you are talking about [`RDB$GET_CONTEXT()`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref25/fblangref25-functions.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-get-context) and [`RDB$SET_CONTEXT()`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref25/fblangref25-functions.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-set-context). You could use `RDB$GET_CONTEXT()` to obtain the current connection (`SESSION_ID`) and transaction id (`TRANSACTION_ID`). These values values can be used for `MON$ATTACHMENT_ID` and `MON$TRANSACTION_ID` in the monitoring tables. I don't think the other variables in the `SYSTEM` namespace are interesting, and those in `USER_SESSION` and `USER_TRANSACTION` are all user-defined (and initially those namespaces are empty).

It is far easier to use the [`CURRENT_CONNECTION`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref25/fblangref25-contextvars.html#fblangref25-contextvars-current-connection) and [`CURRENT_TRANSACTION`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref25/fblangref25-contextvars-current-transaction.html) context variables within a statement. As documented in `doc\README.monitoring_tables.txt` in the Firebird installation:

> System variables CURRENT_CONNECTION and CURRENT_TRANSACTION could be used to select data about the current (for the caller) connection and transaction respectively. These variables correspond to the ID columns of the appropriate monitoring tables.

Note: my answer is largely based on Firebird 2.5.

Answer (score 1):

To present statistics by specific tables I use this SQL (FB 3)

```sql
select t.mon$table_name,trim(
case when r.mon$record_seq_reads>0 then 'Non index Reads: '||r.mon$record_seq_reads else '' end||
case when r.mon$record_idx_reads>0 then ' Index Reads: '||r.mon$record_idx_reads else '' end||
case when r.mon$record_inserts>0 then ' Inserts: '||r.mon$record_inserts else '' end||
case when r.mon$record_updates>0 then ' Updates: '||r.mon$record_updates else '' end||
case when r.mon$record_deletes>0 then ' Deletes: '||r.mon$record_deletes else '' end)
from MON$TABLE_STATS t
join mon$record_stats r on r.mon$stat_id=t.mon$record_stat_id
where t.mon$table_name not starting 'RDB$' and r.mon$stat_group=2
order by 1
```